# Excel VBA Output range skipping columns when not desired

Tags: excel, vba

I've built some VBA to aid in moving records from incorrect tabs to their correct tabs.  I've worked out the logic to SUM the dynamic ranges, since the outputs may be of varying size per each refresh.

The issue I am experiencing is in the SUM output I've coded, in which it skipping certain columns when I do not want it to.  The columns being skipped are `H (col 8)`, `L (col 12)`, and `R col (18)`.  The designed column output range is `3 to 41`.   The output is set to overwrite a SUM formula which, by previous design of the template which generates the sheet (not my own design), is hard-coded and not summing the correct range of cells within the given column.

```
For x = 3 To 41
    Set r = Range(Cells(6, x), Cells(6, x).End(xlDown))
    r.End(xlDown) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `.End(..)` stops as soon as it hits a blank cell, I assume that those columns have blank cells in them somewhere and that your Sum is getting deposited in an earlier row/cell instead of where you expect.